# How to remove or change Recyclerview footer?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using this [EndlessRecyclerView.java](https://github.com/alashow/dotjpg/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tm/alashow/dotjpg/ui/view/EndlessRecyclerView.java) class to add footer or load more view to the `RecyclerView`. I have set a footer using the `setProgressView()` of the `EndlessRecyclerView.java` i.e.

```
mRecyclerView.setProgressView(R.layout.recyclerview_footer_layout);
```

Now after a specific situation, say after a network timeout, I want to change the `TextView` value in footer. But I am unable to do so using the follwing code:

```
View progressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_footer_layout, null);
progressViewText = (TextView) progressView.findViewById(R.id.loadMoreText);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: is there any method like mRecyclerView.getProgressView?

Comment: to add footer you have to add one extar param to your list...remove that extra param and notify adapter

Comment: @Khizar I am using a custom RecyclerView class

Comment: Not sure about the EndlessRecyclerView you mention here but did you try `setProgressView(null);` to remove the view?

Comment: @HRaval can you pe specific please.

Comment: in that custome class i.e RecyclerView class make a function getProgressView(){ return progressView;} get that view and then get required textView

Comment: how did you add footer? can you provide your code? i ll modify it as per your need

Comment: @HRaval I used a custom class. The link is in the question. I figured it out and now everything is working.